# How do I get @JsonView to work with MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, json-view

So I am migrating all of my controllers to using a DTO object as previously they used the persistence objects.

I have chosen to make use of [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#defining-mapper) for this.

My problem is I have seemingly lost the ability to apply `@JsonView` to this response, as now the response when applying the view is `{}` (empty).

My question is, should this be possible to combine MapStruct and Jackson serialisation or will I be required to create a DTO class for each of the views that I currently use?

My class structure is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String name;
    // Etc
}

public class UserDto {
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String name;
    // Etc
}

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    User toUser(UserDto userDto);
    UserDto toUserDto(User user);
}

public class UserController() {
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(path = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Page<UserDto> userPage(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> filters, Pageable page) {
        return service.findAllUser(filters, page).map(mapper::toUserDto);
    }

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(path = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public UserDto singleUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return mapper.toUserDto(service.findById(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. Can you please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Using MapStruct and `@JsonView` defeats the purpose of using MapStruct (in my opinion). Why not create an object per view? For example `UserSummaryDto` and map from your `User` into the `UserSummaryDto` this way you don't need to use `@JsonView` and JacksonWould deserialize everything properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @Filip, that is the solution I went for in the end